# How to connect eXist database with Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, exist-db

Is there any way to connect the eXist xml database with netbeans IDE?Is there any JDBC driver for it for connection or I have to configure manually all the connection URL for that?

Answer (score 1):

Currently working with the same question as you. This is what I've found so far:

You have to include "C:\Program Files\eXist\exist.jar" (or where ever your exist-db is installed) and I think you have to add "C:\Program Files\eXist\lib\core\xmldb.jar".

After that I think you could chose from one of these:

http://exist-db.org/exist/devguide_xmldb.xml

http://exist-db.org/devguide_xmlrpc.xml